# Как в Create React App использовать папку images внутри src/?

Tags: reactjs, изображения, create-react-app

Мне комфортней писать пути для картинок так:

```
<img src="images/logo.svg"/>
```

Но CRA почему то не дает мне сделать так, и приходится папку `images` хранить в папке public. Теперь все ок, я могу прописывать пути картинок так как я хочу. Проблема следующая, я не могу внутри SCSS кода написать так:

```
.logo {
  background-image: url('../images/logo.svg); // ./images, /images, images - не работает
}
```

Для scss мне приходится создавать папку уже внутри src. Мне так очень не удобно. Подскажите, я могу создать одну папку images и хранить все ресурсы там и использовать как в html, так и в scss поместив только в директорию public или scss?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете создать папку `images` внутри `src`

и подключать картинки таким образом:

```
<img src={require("images/logo.svg")} />
```

В `css` будет обычное подключение картинок:

```
background-image: url("images/logo.svg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете импортировать картинку как обьект для вставки в код.

```
import imaga from '../../images/paper.jpg';
<img src={imaga} alt='this is top image' />
```

в css:

```
.dialog {
    background-image: url("../../images/paper.jpg");
}
```